# Wait till the promise is finished and return true or false

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to wait within a method till a promise return.

```
public loginOffline(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.database.getItem('currentUser', 'login').then(data => {
        this.userLogin = data;
        console.log(username + ' ' + this.userLogin.username + ' ' + password + ' ' + this.userLogin.password);
        if (username === this.userLogin.username && password === this.userLogin.password) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return false;
    });

}

/********* call the method and descide what to do **************/
if (loginOffline('myname', 'mypassword'){
    // Do something.....
} else {
    // Do something else .....
}
......
```

this doesn't work. The method to call this loginOffline method just want to know if the login in was successful. I tried many things but nothing worked out.

Can anybody help. Thanks a lot
Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have to chain the promise with another `then`.
Call this way:

```
loginOffline('myname', 'mypassword').then(result =>{
   if(result){
     //do something
   }else{
     //do something else
   }
})
```

More on [promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Promise` object like follows:

```
public loginOffline(username: string, password: string) {
  return this.database.getItem('currentUser', 'login').then(data => {
      this.userLogin = data;
      console.log(username + ' ' + this.userLogin.username + ' ' + password + ' ' + this.userLogin.password );
      if (username === this.userLogin.username && password === this.userLogin.password) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      return false;
    });   
}

loginOffline('myname', 'mypassword').then((result) => {
    if(result) {
      // true was returned
    } else {
      // false was returned
    }
 })
```

Comment: [this is an antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: @suraj I took a look at the link you gave me and edited the answer. Can you please take a look and let me know if I understood it correctly. Please feel free to edit and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you wont have `resolve(bool)` since it is not a parameter anymore.. just `return boolean_value`..

Comment: Inside the callbacks where you return `resolve(true)` or `resolve(false)` you should just be returning `true` or `false` (as in the original code in the question). There is no `resolve` function in scope where you try to use it, but more importantly the handler callbacks for a Promise will automatically wrap any returned value up as a Promise without you having to do anything special.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @suraj is the correct one, simply use another `.then()` around the returned result, but an alternative is to use the `await`/`async` keywords to rewrite the code.

```
 public async loginOffline(username: string, password: string) {
    try {
      this.userLogin = await this.database.getItem('currentUser', 'login');
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log(username + ' ' + this.userLogin.username + ' ' + password + ' ' + this.userLogin.password );
    return (
      username === this.userLogin.username &&
      password === this.userLogin.password);
  }

// This code must also be inside a function marked as 'async':
/********* call the method and descide what to do **************/
if(await loginOffline('myname', 'mypassword'){
// Do something.....
} else {
// Do something else .....
}
......
```

Note that every `async` function will automatically convert anything it returns into a Promise, so you have to use `async` all the way up the call tree. Or, if for some reason you don't want to make the caller `async` you can just use `then` on the result as before:

```
// If the caller cannot be marked `async`:
/********* call the method and descide what to do **************/
loginOffline('myname', 'mypassword').then(result => {
  if (result) {
  // Do something.....
  } else {
  // Do something else .....
  }
});
......
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the solution here:

```
function GetUserPemission(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   getdata().then((data)=>{
      if(data){
            resolve(true);
      }else{
        resolve(false);
      }
    }).catch((error)=>{
            resolve(false);
    })
  })
}

function getdata(){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ setTimeout(()=>{resolve("Data")},100)})
}

GetUserPemission().then((data)=>{
        alert(data);
});
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the other comment.. wrapping with new promise each time is [an anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)